# How to use Open Type Fonts in Java?

Tags: java, fonts, opentype

Is there a way to read Open Type fonts in Java the same way as I do with TrueType fonts?

This works perfectly for TTF but I did not figure out yet how to do the same with Open Type fonts.

```
Font f = Font.createFont( Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,
new FileInputStream("f.ttf") );
```

Please note I cannot rely on installed fonts. I provide the font with my program but don't want to install it system-wide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is Open Type Font support in java (not free atleast), iText claimed to have such support, tried it a few month ago and it didn't work, what worked for me is a program called FontForge which I used to create a ttf from the otf which I then used.

Answer (score 4):

[Java OpenType font support depends on your OS and JDK version.](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/opentype.html#JAVASUPPORT)

Prior to Java 6, you can only use TrueType flavored OpenType fonts. With Java 6 you can use all OpenType fonts but you won't benefit from advanced typographic features like ligatures.

Answer (score 3):

Open Type (`.otf`) font files are not supported in Java 1.6. From Java 1.7, support is added:

```java
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("MyFont.otf"));
font  = font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 40);

label.setFont(font);
```

More details:

- http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6992611
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/adoptionGuide/#swing