# JTextField crops text when using custom TrueType font. How to make it display text normally?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtextfield, truetype

So, the problem is definitely with the font. Question is how to make the text field display text fully. Example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;

class Example extends JFrame{
    public Example(){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Font myFont = null;
        try {
            URL link = new URL("http://rghost.ru/download/50564305/e6efddd74f598b86f7ac704cab72e430a490bc7f/digital-7.ttf");
            ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(link.openStream());
            File font_file = new File("font.ttf");
            if(!font_file.exists())
                font_file.createNewFile();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(font_file);
            fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
            myFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, font_file);
        } catch (FontFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JTextField myField = new JTextField("sample text");
        myField.setFont(myFont.deriveFont(32.0f));
        add(myField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300, 400);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Example();
    }
}
```

The font is Digital 7: [dafont.com](http://www.dafont.com/digital-7.font)
PROBLEM SOLVED
The solution is to convert the font [here](http://www.dafont.com/digital-7.font) (or other such place) to PFM and use it like that:

```
Font myFont = Font.createFont(Font.TYPE1_FONT, new File("res/my_font.pfm"));
```

Comment: @AndrewVershinin Edit your text above and make it a question.

Comment: If the font is available on the net & is not too big, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that hot-links to it.  I suspect the problem is with the `Font` rather than Java.

Comment: @AndrewThompson
Font is [link](http://www.dafont.com/digital-7.font)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Here it goes.

Comment: My first gut feeling is that the font isn't providing appropriate information for it to be rendered properly

Comment: BTW - by 'hot-link' I meant the code itself should be able to use an URL to load the font. @MadProgrammer  Yes, that was my first impression as well.  It is also my 2nd & 3rd impression.  ;)

Comment: Cool.  I [found](http://superuser.com/a/122037/99314) a page at http://onlinefontconverter.com/font?id=p1 that claims to (sometimes) fix invalid fonts, but cannot locate one that will simply report the validity.  Try running it through that first.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Did it. The problem is still here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is with the `Font` rather than Java.

I [found](https://superuser.com/a/122037/99314) a page at http://onlinefontconverter.com/font?id=p1 that claims to (sometimes) fix invalid fonts, but cannot locate one that will simply report the validity. Try running it through that first.

Comment: +1, interesting link, but [I'm doubt, but ....](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18462739/714968)

Answer (score -1):

```
myField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40,40)); // where the first argument is the width of the component,
                                                //  and 2nd is the height(that's what you need )
```

Comment: See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Thanks for posting the link.