# Java Custom Font Distortion

Tags: java, swing, fonts, label

I am writing an application which includes a .ttf file for the fonts of the GUI. Loading the font seems no problem, however when using `deriveFont()` method to edit the size the font seems to be distorted (e.g. not on the same line, parts missing from letters, skewing,..).

Why is this? Is there a way round?

Code to load the font:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fonts/lg.ttf");
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
leagueGothic =  Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
ge.registerFont(leagueGothic);
```

And then changing the size with `deriveFont()`

```
label.setFont(leagueGothic.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, scale(50, 'x'));
```

`scale(int, char)` is just a method to change the size proportional to the size of the application window, it returns an `int`.

Comment: [can you test with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461331/ttf-and-otf-versions-of-source-sans-pro-are-differently-displayed-in-swing-nimb/18462739#18462739)

Answer (score 2):

In your call to `deriveFont()`, the method `scale(int, char)` "it returns an `int`." It should probably return a `float`, as required [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont%28int,%20float%29) for the `size` parameter.

Comment: Hm it hasn't done the trick, text font is as distorted as it always has been.

Comment: _Distortion_ makes me wonder about `AffineTransform`; without an [mctre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's hard to tell.